# Exec : display stdout "live"

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I have this simple script :

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('coffee -cw my_file.coffee', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

where I simply execute a command to compile a coffee-script file. But stdout never get displayed in the console, because the command never ends (because of the -w option of coffee).
If I execute the command directly from the console I get message like this :

```
18:05:59 - compiled my_file.coffee
```

My question is : is it possible to display these messages with the node.js exec ? If yes how ? !

Comment: I came here looking for capturing stdout from Python executable. Note that all of the below will work, but you need to run python with a "-u" option, to make outout unbuffered and thereby have live updates.

Answer (score 323, accepted):

Don't use `exec`. Use [`spawn`](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) which is an `EventEmmiter` object. Then you can listen to `stdout`/`stderr` events (`spawn.stdout.on('data',callback..)`) *as they happen*.

From NodeJS documentation:

```js
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    ls    = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data.toString());
});

ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data.toString());
});

ls.on('exit', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code.toString());
});
```

`exec` buffers the output and usually returns it when the command has finished executing.

Comment: Very nice. FYI: The stdout/stderr events callback argument 'data' is a buffer so call it with .toString()

Comment: For those of you who can't get spawn to work on Windows, have a look at this great [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17537559/2816199).

Comment: exec is also an EventEmitter at least in latest.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the callback will not be called, whenever the program outputs a newline. If you want to receive "events" from the child process, this process must flush the buffer (`flush(stdout);` in C) in order to fire events in Node.js.

Comment: +1 on exec also being an EventEmitter.. spent 2 hours on refactoring my string into an args array (very long and complicated ffmpeg command line).. only to find out I didn't really need to.

Comment: It seems that when I run this in windows, the thing doesn't actually exit out and I have to hit CTRL+C. Edit: it seems the fix it to run `process.exit()`.

Comment: The question is how do you solve the "progress bar" not being displayed as new line (for example webpack writes the progress into stderr). You can "process.stderr.write('\x1Bc')" every time to clear up the console above, but that's not a solution, because you clean all prior output

Comment: It was helpful for me to find that `process.stdout.write( data.toString() );` prevents adding a newline (like console.log does) after each stdout emission.

Comment: ```var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    git    = spawn('git', ['clone', 'https://github.com/MaxySpark/Text-Clustering.git']);

git.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data.toString());
});

git.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data.toString());
});



git.on('exit', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code.toString());
});```
its only print `stderr: Cloning into 'Text-Clustering'...`

why not printing other output texts?


and why is it on `stderr`?

Comment: Use `ls.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');` in order to not need to convert the buffer with `data.toString()`

Comment: how to you retrieve the output though? the solution here only prints them in callbacks. What if the caller needs the stdout content for something else?

Comment: Use https://github.com/moxystudio/node-cross-spawn . It just works, has the same API, and gives you all of the output from the command.

Comment: How would we achieve the same in a world of promises? That is, if we run something like `promisify(exec)('echo hello')` or `promisify(spawn)('echo world')`

Comment: (Downvoted this answer, as it it wrong) - You can use either spawn or exec in the same way, they both return a ChildProcess object, the difference is that exec spawns a shell (such as bash) to execute the provided command, while spawn execute the command directly (with system execvp function on linux and mac os). You can use exec to output stdout while the command is being executed.

Answer (score 276):

`exec` will also return a ChildProcess object that is an EventEmitter.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var coffeeProcess = exec('coffee -cw my_file.coffee');

coffeeProcess.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data); 
});
```

OR `pipe` the child process's stdout to the main stdout.

```
coffeeProcess.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
```

OR inherit stdio using spawn

```
spawn('coffee -cw my_file.coffee', { stdio: 'inherit' });
```

Comment: Looks like this can be simplified by just using `pipe`: `coffeeProcess.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);`

Comment: @EricFreese's comment is what I was looking for, because I wanted to leverage stdout's characters replacement feature (harnessing protractor in a node script)

Comment: Simpler: `spawn(cmd, argv, { stdio: 'inherit' })`. See https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio for different examples.

Comment: +1 for @MorganTouvereyQuilling's suggestion to use `spawn` with `stdio: 'inherit'`. It produces more accurate output than `exec` and piping `stdout`/`stderr`, for example when displaying the progress information from a `git clone`.

Answer (score 102):

There are already several answers however none of them mention the best (and easiest) way to do this, which is using `spawn` and the [`{ stdio: 'inherit' }` option](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio). It seems to produce the most accurate output, for example when displaying the progress information from a `git clone`.

Simply do this:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

spawn('coffee', ['-cw', 'my_file.coffee'], { stdio: 'inherit' });
```

Credit to @MorganTouvereyQuilling for pointing this out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232192/exec-display-stdout-live/43477289#comment73321259_30084906).

Comment: I found that when the subprocess uses formatted output like colored text, `stdio: "inherit"` preserves that formatting while `child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)` does not.

Comment: This perfectly preserves output even on processes with complex output like the progress bars on npm installs. Awesome!

Comment: why this is not the accepted answer? it was the only one that worked for me and it's just 2 f* lines!!!

Comment: This tip was helpful when executing some Symfony command-line applications that use progress bars. Cheers.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer–only thing that preserves perfect output representation _and_ it's the simplest? yes please

Comment: exactly what I was searching for, great answer, must be accepted

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 28):

Inspired by Nathanael Smith's answer and Eric Freese's comment, it could be as simple as:

```js
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('coffee -cw my_file.coffee').stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
```

Comment: This seems to work fine for simple commands like `ls` but fails for more complex commands such as `npm install`. I even tried piping both stdout and stderr to their respective process objects.

Comment: @linuxdan it may be because npm is writing in stderr (i saw some write the progress bar there). you can pipe also stderr, or extend Tongfa solution to  listen on stderr.

Comment: @linuxdan From what I've seen the most reliable way is `spawn(command, args, { stdio: 'inherit' })`, as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232192/exec-display-stdout-live#comment73321259_30084906

Comment: Best answer, Thanks for this. Worked like a charm

Answer (score 23):

I'd just like to add that one small issue with outputting the buffer strings from a spawned process with `console.log()` is that it adds newlines, which can spread your spawned process output over additional lines. If you output `stdout` or `stderr` with `process.stdout.write()` instead of `console.log()`, then you'll get the console output from the spawned process 'as is'.

I saw that solution here:
[Node.js: printing to console without a trailing newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157497/node-js-printing-to-console-without-a-trailing-newline)

Hope that helps someone using the solution above (which is a great one for live output, even if it is from the documentation).

Comment: For even more accurate output use `spawn(command, args, { stdio: 'inherit' })`, as suggested by @MorganTouvereyQuilling here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232192/exec-display-stdout-live#comment73321259_30084906

Answer (score 21):

I have found it helpful to add a custom exec script to my utilities that do this.

utilities.js

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process')

module.exports.exec = (command) => {
  const process = exec(command)
  
  process.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data.toString())
  })
  
  process.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data.toString())
  })
  
  process.on('exit', (code) => {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code.toString())
  })
}
```

app.js

```js
const { exec } = require('./utilities.js')
    
exec('coffee -cw my_file.coffee')
```

Comment: It is working properly but its format is not the same as it comes while installing npm like the progress bar, and color text.

Answer (score 5):

After reviewing all the other answers, I ended up with this:

```
function oldSchoolMakeBuild(cb) {
    var makeProcess = exec('make -C ./oldSchoolMakeBuild',
         function (error, stdout, stderr) {
             stderr && console.error(stderr);
             cb(error);
        });
    makeProcess.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        process.stdout.write('oldSchoolMakeBuild: '+ data);
    });
}
```

Sometimes `data` will be multiple lines, so the `oldSchoolMakeBuild` header will appear once for multiple lines.  But this didn't bother me enough to change it.

Answer (score 3):

child_process.spawn returns an object with stdout and stderr streams. 
You can tap on the stdout stream to read data that the child process sends back to Node. stdout being a stream has the "data", "end", and other events that streams have. spawn is best used to when you want the child process to return a large amount of data to Node - image processing, reading binary data etc.

so you can solve your problem using child_process.spawn as used below.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
ls = spawn('coffee -cw my_file.coffee');

ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data.toString());
});

ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data.toString());
});

ls.on('exit', function (code) {
  console.log('code ' + code.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an async helper function written in typescript that seems to do the trick for me. I guess this will not work for long-lived processes but still might be handy for someone?

```
import * as child_process from "child_process";

private async spawn(command: string, args: string[]): Promise<{code: number | null, result: string}> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const spawn = child_process.spawn(command, args)
        let result: string
        spawn.stdout.on('data', (data: any) => {
            if (result) {
                reject(Error('Helper function does not work for long lived proccess'))
            }
            result = data.toString()
        })
        spawn.stderr.on('data', (error: any) => {
            reject(Error(error.toString()))
        })
        spawn.on('exit', code => {
            resolve({code, result})
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another way to do it:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

export const execCommand = async (command) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const [cmd, ...args] = command.split(' ');
    const childProcess = spawn(cmd, args);
    childProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      process.stdout.write(data.toString());
    });
    childProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      process.stderr.write(data.toString());
    });
    childProcess.on('error', (error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
    childProcess.on('exit', (code) => {
      if (code === 0) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject(new Error(`Command exited with code ${code}.`));
      }
    });
  });
};
```

This code gives and ability to get real-time output from executed command and redirect all stdout and stderr to parent process. It also allows using the command the same way you use it in bash/sh (single string input). Here I use `process.stdout.write` for more accurate output instead of `console.log` that is used in other answers.

Usage:

```js
await execCommand('sudo apt-get update');
await execCommand('sudo apt-get install -y docker.io docker-compose');
```

Note: compared to `exec` it does not support execution of multiple commands using `&&`. So each single command should be executed with a single `execCommand` statement.

And here is a simplified version that supports both realtime streaming and shell execution:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

export const execCommand = async (command) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const childProcess = spawn(command, { 
      stdio: 'inherit',
      shell: true
    });
    childProcess.on('error', (error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
    childProcess.on('exit', (code) => {
      if (code === 0) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject(new Error(`Command exited with code ${code}.`));
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Usage:

```js
await execCommand('sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y docker.io docker-compose');
```