# npm ERR spawn ENOENT

Tags: javascript, socket.io, npm

I am new to Node and I have this double error which is confusing for noobs like me...

Here is *exactly* what I did :

I installed the last version of Node on a clear directory, created an application, and created the following json package file:

```
{
    "name":"Radiorev",
    "version":"0.0.1",
    "private":"true",
    "dependencies":{
        "express":"3.3.5",
        "socket.io":"0.9.16"
    }
}
```

When I execute `npm install`, I get the following error:

> spawnENOENT" error at the end of the installation

Why I am getting this error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using nodejs's spawn causes "unknown option -- " and "\[Error: spawn ENOENT\]" errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516772/using-nodejss-spawn-causes-unknown-option-and-error-spawn-enoent-err)