# CoffeeScript and Cake Error

Tags: coffeescript

I try to get the cake example from http://arcturo.github.io/library/coffeescript/05_compiling.html to run. But that leads to a strange error:

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

This is my Cakefile (just copied from "Little book on CoffeeSCript")

```
fs = require 'fs'

{print} = require 'sys'
{spawn} = require 'child_process'

build = (callback) ->
  coffee = spawn 'coffee', ['-c', '-o', 'lib', 'src']
  coffee.stderr.on 'data', (data) ->
    process.stderr.write data.toString()
  coffee.stdout.on 'data', (data) ->
    print data.toString()
  coffee.on 'exit', (code) ->
    callback?() if code is 0

task 'build', 'Build lib/ from src/', ->
  build()
```

I'm using Coffee 1.6.3 and node 0.10.20.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: what's in events.js at line 72? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: I don't find the sources that are used on my system. If I donwload the sources I find only a comment in line 72 ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an explanation for what is happening here:

[Using nodejs's spawn causes "unknown option -- " and "[Error: spawn ENOENT]" errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516772/using-nodejss-spawn-causes-unknown-option-and-error-spawn-enoent-err)

The solution was to use *exec* instead of *spawn*

Answer (score 1):

ENOENT typically means "I looked for the thing you told me to find and I didn't find it". From the example page:

`For example, create a file called Cakefile, and two directories, lib and src.`

Do you have both of those?

Comment: Thanks, that's close, thx. The coffee.cmd is what spawn is missing, since spawn can only start binaries, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, spawn doesn't handle '.cmd' or '.bat' without file extension.

repalce

```
coffee = spawn 'coffee', ['-c', '-o', 'lib', 'src']
```

with

```
coffee = spwan 'coffee.cmd', ['-c','-o','lib','src']
```