# AppGyver Steroids - browser window does not open with QR code (win8)

Tags: node.js, cordova, windows-8, phonegap-plugins, steroids

http://forums.appgyver.com/#!/@appgyver:15157

Basically, I did a complete install on Win7/64 and it worked perfectly(!) Then tried the same on a Win8/64 laptop. The Win8 had problems with SPAWN as per these posts:

- https://moot.it/i/appgyver/steroids:error-installing-steroids-o
- [Using nodejs's spawn causes "unknown option -- " and "[Error: spawn ENOENT]" errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516772/using-nodejss-spawn-causes-unknown-option-and-error-spawn-enoent-err)

So I copied the nodejs+Steriods CLI install at this location, `%Homepath%\AppData\Roaming\npm`, from Win7 to Win8. Everything with Steroids seems to work fine, EXCEPT I cannot get the browser window to open with a QR code. Tried disabling firewall, but no luck.

Any ideas on how to debug this?

Comment: Just realized Win7 installed steroids@3.1.5, but win8 was trying to install steroids@3.1.7,  manually tried steroids@3.1.5 and still no luck

Comment: Win7 updated to 3.1.7 just fine. Win8 also works if I log the target (QR URL) in open.js and manually paste into the browser.

Comment: I opened an issue to our [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids/issues/49) – we'll figure this out. Do tell us if you find a solution before we do!