# Gulp Error on spawn CMD while running "gulp serve"

Tags: node.js, gulp

```
D:\Web\TeamBW\TeamBWSite>gulp serve
[19:15:29] Using gulpfile D:\Web\TeamBW\TeamBWSite\gulpfile.js
[19:15:29] Starting 'styles'...
[19:15:30] 'styles' all files 0 B
[19:15:30] Finished 'styles' after 492 ms
[19:15:30] Starting 'serve'...
[19:15:30] Finished 'serve' after 70 ms
[WSK] Local URL: http://localhost:3000
[WSK] External URL: http://192.168.1.5:3000
[WSK] Serving files from: .tmp
[WSK] Serving files from: app
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32)
    at child_process.js:1144:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

D:\Web\TeamBW\TeamBWSite>
```

I get that error while trying to run 'gulp serve' in my google web starter kit directory.  Previous to running 'gulp serve' I ran these commands

1. cd TeamBWSite
2. npm install
3. npm install gulp -g

I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using nodejs's spawn causes "unknown option -- " and "\[Error: spawn ENOENT\]" errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516772/using-nodejss-spawn-causes-unknown-option-and-error-spawn-enoent-err)