# `npm start` gives lifecycle error and exits with status 9

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux, ubuntu, npm

So far, I have looked similar issues like [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/how-to-solve-npm-error-npm-err-code-elifecycle) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60608201/npm-start-giving-errors). The solution seems to be:

```
rm package-lock.json
npm cache clean --force
npm install
npm start
```

I have tried these steps, but keep getting the same error:

```js
> client@0.1.0 start /home/ubuntu/react/client
> react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start

/usr/bin/node: bad option: --openssl-legacy-provider
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 9
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start`
npm ERR! Exit status 9
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2021-12-20T09_28_07_369Z-debug.log
```

The output of `/home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2021-12-20T09_28_07_369Z-debug.log` is:

```js
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v12.18.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~prestart: client@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: client@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: PATH: /usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/ubuntu/react/client/node_modules/.bin:/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/react/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/ubuntu/go/bin
9 verbose lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: CWD: /home/ubuntu/react/client
10 silly lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start' ]
11 silly lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 9  signal: null
12 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 9
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid client@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /home/ubuntu/react/client
16 verbose Linux 5.8.0-63-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v12.18.2
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 9
22 error client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start`
22 error Exit status 9
23 error Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 9, true ]
```

All the posts I am seeing seem to be having an exit status of 1 and while I have a 9 instead. What could the issue be? From what I have read around, an exit status 9 means that the process is being killed by the system, but I don't know why or how to find out.

Comment: try to update xour node version from 12 to 16

Comment: @Tobias, Thanks. I didn't even realize I was running such an old version of node. This resolved the issues.

Answer (score 8):

In case a node upgrade is not available on a user's machine for whatever reason (e.g. no admin rights or something), then I found that this fixed it:
change where the argument appears in the command, so in package.json instead of this:

`"start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start"`

do this:

`"start": "react-scripts start --openssl-legacy-provider"`

source: https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template/issues/336

Answer (score 0):

This works for me
npm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node

source: https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template/issues/336

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).