# Gulp - Execute endless process trough shell (like Netstat, for example)

Tags: shell, gulp

Is there some how to make gulp execute a shell command that's never stops like neststat and display the results on the screen in real time ? I used this...

```
exec('netstat', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    cb(err);
});
```

It's works, the netstat executes fine, but I cannot see results on the screen because it's the kind of the file that's never terminates, so the console.lot(stdout) will never be executed.

Any solution that's can solve it ? ty !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [exec: display stdout "live"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232192/exec-display-stdout-live)

Comment: You are right...that topic was enough for me. ty, @t.niese !