# How to run a command with no args in 'spawn'

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn, pwd

Hello I am trying to run terminal commands from NodeJS and am trying to use the spawn command, I had been using exec but am trying spawn now for the stdout.

All the examples I've bene reading, like this one:
[Exec : display stdout "live"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232192/exec-display-stdout-live)

Use commands with multiple arguments, like in the example above, the command they run with spawn is :

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn, ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);
```

Which is '$ ls -lh /usr'

I am trying to just run the command 'pwd' with no args, but all the ways I've been trying to do so (like below) have resulted in an '' error

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn, ls = spawn('pwd');
```

or

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn, ls = spawn('pwd', []);

stderr: usage: pwd [-L | -P]
```

Answer (score 1):

Providing arguments in `spawn` is not mandatory. In your question, `spawn` is working and and that's why the error you see is actually the output of `stderr` after `spawn('pwd')` has been executed.

Working example of `pwd` with `spawn`:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const pwd = spawn('pwd');

pwd.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

pwd.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

pwd.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/AlienatedTidyDatalogs