# Logging output while running commander program

Tags: node.js, node-commander

I'm using [commander.js](https://github.com/tj/commander.js) to run a program that keeps Node running (watching for files and running tasks).

It seems like Commander is waiting until the command exits to log any output. Is there a way to log output to the console while the command is running?

```js
import { program } from 'commander';
import chokidar from 'chokidar';

program
  .command('dev')
  .description('Start the development server')
  .action(async (options, command) => {
    // Doesn't get logged unless program exits
    console.log(`...`);
    chokidar.watch('...')
  });

// This also won't log until command is finished
process.stdout.write('...')

program.parse();
```

Comment: Do you see the same problems if you replace the call to program.parse with a direct call to what the action handler is doing?

Comment: Sure did. And that led me to realize that I was running the program through another script that wasn't properly [piping the output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30084906/2241124).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commander does not modify the behaviour of `console.log` or `process.stdout.write`, so the problems with the delayed output are something other than Commander.

Note: you should be calling `program.parseAsync()` since you have an async action handler, but that isn't the solution to your problem.

(Disclaimer: I am a maintainer of Commander.)

Comment: This, along with [the comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77359501/logging-output-while-running-commander-program?noredirect=1#comment136385939_77359501), helped me get to the bottom of the issue, which was unrelated to Commander.

The program using commander was launched from another program which was responsible for holding back the output. [Making this change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30084906/2241124) fixed the issue.