# Print an output in one line using console.log()

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to print the output in the same line by using `console.log()` in JavaScript? I know `console.log()` always returns a new line. For example, have the output of multiple consecutive `console.log()` calls be:

```
"0,1,2,3,4,5,"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome JavaScript developer console: Is it possible to call console.log() without a newline?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627646/chrome-javascript-developer-console-is-it-possible-to-call-console-log-withou)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Couldn't you just put them in the same call, or use a loop?

```js
  var one = "1"
  var two = "2"
  var three = "3"

  var combinedString = one + ", " + two + ", " + three

  console.log(combinedString) // "1, 2, 3"
  console.log(one + ", " + two + ", " + three) // "1, 2, 3"

  var array = ["1", "2", "3"];
  var string = "";
  array.forEach(function(element){
      string += element;
  });
  console.log(string); //123
```

Answer (score 92):

In Node.js there is a way: [`process.stdout`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_stdout)

So, this may work:

```
process.stdout.write(`${index},`);
```

where `index` is a current data and `,` is a delimiter.

Also you can check same topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157497/node-js-printing-to-console-without-a-trailing-newline).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was scratching my head, as the Hacker Rank was not accepting my answer, even though it was correct, as I was using console.log(arr.join('  ')); as it was getting a line break.

Comment: Same here. Don't know how dull HackerRankd is made in some cases :D

Comment: Cool. Working fine.

Answer (score 33):

You could just use the spread operator `...`

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

console.log(...array);
```

Answer (score 11):

So if you want to print numbers from 1 to 5 you could do the following:

```js
    var array = [];
    for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
       array.push(i);
    }
    console.log(array.join(','));
```

Output:
'1,2,3,4,5'

Array.join(); is a very useful function that returns a string by concatenating the elements of an array. Whatever string you pass as parameter is inserted between all the elements.

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 8):

You can just `console.log` the strings all in the same line, as so:

```
console.log("1" + "2" + "3");
```

And to create a new line, use `\n`:

```
console.log("1,2,3\n4,5,6")
```

If you are running your app on node.js, you can use an [ansi escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to clear the line `\u001b[2K\u001b[0E`:

```
console.log("old text\u001b[2K\u001b[0Enew text")
```

Comment: Any reason why that ANSI sequence is so complicated? `console.log("old text\rnew")` does exactly the same thing.

Comment: @DanDascalescu While that is true, escape sequences are consistent in behavior throughout terminals. A carriage return *may* have different behavior on other terminal emulators. On most emulators, it only goes to the 0th column and does not clear the line in question unlike the sequence above.

Comment: Great to know the difference! To illustrate that better, you might want to have the older text be longer, e.g. `console.log('old text longer than the new one\u001b[2K\u001b[0Enew text');`. Mentioning that `\u001b` is the Unicode "Escape" character, and a dissection of that cryptic string would help too.

Comment: To fill out some more specifics (these are all from the article linked by @bitbyte) The All sequences start with ESC (`\u001b` in javascript string) The `[` indicates the start of a Control Sequence Introducer (CSI). Next is `2K` which `CSI n K` clears a line. "If n is 2, clear entire line" Now we start another sequence `CSI n E` "Moves cursor to beginning of the line n lines down."

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the spread operator `(...)`

```
console.log(...array);
```

The "Spread" operator will feed all the elements of your array to the `console.log` function.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it like this:

```js
let s = "";
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  s += i.toString();
  if (i != 5) {
    s += ",";
  }
}
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible directly in a browser environment. You'll need to create some buffer to hold values that you want to print on the same line.

In previous answers there are examples of using arrays and loops. As an alternative you can solve it functionally:

```js
const print = ((buffer = '') => arg => {
  if (arg !== '\n') {
    buffer += arg
  } else {
    console.log(buffer)
    buffer = ''
  }
})()

print('x')
print('y')
print('z')    
print('\n') // flush buffer
```

Or you can use object setters

```js
const c = {
  buffer: '',
  set log(val) {
    if (val !== '\n') {
      this.buffer += val
    } else {
      console.log(this.buffer)
      this.buffer = ''
    }
  }
}

c.log = 'foo'
c.log = 42
c.log = 'bar'
c.log = '\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print them as an array

if you write:

```
console.log([var1,var2,var3,var4]);
```

you can get

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use The  Spread Operator. The "log" method Prints It's args in a Single Line and You can Give it The Elements of the Array as individual Arguments By Spreading the Array.

`console.log(... array);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use comma delimiter:

```
console.log(1,2,3,4);
```

but if you want commas to show up in the output then you will need to use strings:

```
console.log('1,','2,','3,','4');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this instead. It's simple.

```
    var first_name = ["Ram", "Sita", "Hari", "Ravi", "Babu"];
    name_list = "";
    name_list += first_name;
    console.log(name_list);
    // OR you can just typecast to String to print them in a single line separated by comma as follows;
    console.log(first_name.toString());
    // OR just do the following
    console.log(""+first_name);
    // Output: Ram,Sita,Hari,Ravi,Babu
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read how to [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use process.stdout.write

Like This in a loop..

```
process.stdout.write(`${arr[i]} `)
```