# While running JavaScript in Terminal (using rhino) how do I print in a single line using print() function?

Tags: javascript, rhino

The function `print()` gives newline character at the end.

**following is the JS code**

```
print("first");
Things =["car","building"]
for (var i = Things.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
{
    print(Things[i])
}
```

**the Output I get for the code above is**

```
first
building
car
```

**Whereas I intended to print like this**

```
firstbuildingcar
```

### How do I print them in a single line using print() function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [printing output same line using console log in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28620087/printing-output-same-line-using-console-log-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array and join it using a blank delimiter:

```
print(['uno','dos','tres'].join("")); // outputs "unodostres"
```

You don't need to loop.  You do need to create your array before joining it (whereas you're printing one standalone string that's not part of an array, and then looping over your array).

If you want to reverse the print order of your array-- which it looks like your loop is doing-- just `reverse()` it before you `join()`:

```
print(['uno','dos','tres'].reverse().join("")); // outputs "tresdosuno"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Things =["car","building"]
res ="first"
for (var i = Things.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
{
    res=res+Things[i]
}
print(res);
```