# Is there any way to console.log without a newline?

Tags: javascript, console.log

I want to `console.log` my array like this without newlines:

```js
const myarr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];

myarr.forEach((e) => console.log(e));
```

Actual result:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Desired result:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

or

```
12345
```

Comment: `console.log(...myarr)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome JavaScript developer console: Is it possible to call console.log() without a newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627646/chrome-javascript-developer-console-is-it-possible-to-call-console-log-withou) Or more specifically [printing output same line using console log in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28620087/215552)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could spread the array. Then all values are taken as parameters.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(...array);
```

Comment: thanks, but if I want to console.log 2 variables without a newline

Comment: Almost exactly the same as [this answer on a duplicate question...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52446467/215552)

Answer (score 5):

To answer the actual question, there are two possible answers:

1. If you are running in a browser, then by default, no, but according to this answer from [Chrome JavaScript developer console: Is it possible to call console.log() without a newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627646/chrome-javascript-developer-console-is-it-possible-to-call-console-log-withou#answer-41817778) you can by making a virtual console on top of the browser's console.
2. If you're using node, then you can use `process.stdout.write(msg)` from this answer [Chrome JavaScript developer console: Is it possible to call console.log() without a newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627646/chrome-javascript-developer-console-is-it-possible-to-call-console-log-withou#answer-38317398)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead.

```js
let myarr = [1,2,3,4,5];
const result = myarr.reduce((a, c) => `${a}${c}`, '');
console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing a separate console.log for every element in the array? You can just do:

```
console.log(myarr);
```

Or, if your array has objects in it and you want to see them all unrolled, you could do:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(myarr));
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to stringify your output.

So either using something like `JSON.stringify(myarr)`
or

```
let string = '';
for(let i = 1; i < 6; i += 1) {
  string += i + ' ';
}
console.log(string);
```

Edit: Btw, I'd suggest using camelCase when working with javascript. It's become a standard when defining variables and methods.

See:  https://techterms.com/definition/camelcase