# Getting much output from the number of user input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python

In Python I use "for x in range(j)" and j is defined from user input, for example

```
j = int(input())
for x in range(j)
print(j)
```

if I input j as 3, the output will be

```
3
3
3
```

My question is, how do i do it with javascript?

I tried to do it with array, etc. Nothing seems to work, sorry im really new at coding and need to learn 2 programming language for my college

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with [**prompt**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp) function

```js
const printData = () =>{

  let num = prompt("Please input a number", "3") // second parameter is the default value
  if(isNaN(num)){
    console.error(`${num} is an invalid number`)
    return
  }

 for(let i=0;i<num;i++){
    console.log(num)
  }
}

printData()
```

Comment: thank you so much for this, i've ben trying many things but you solved it right away, guess need to learn way more haha

Comment: oh yeah, one more questions may i ask, how do you add the output together?

Comment: @Kyanite check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28620087/print-an-output-in-one-line-using-console-log

Comment: i'm sorry, i mean by my question is to calculate them all togheter, like 3 +3 + 3 so the output will be 9, i know my questions is weird, its because the "3" is actually another user input that needs to be the form of total, like inputting price from many products

Comment: @Kyanite you can try `num**num`