# console.dir - how to show what object it applies to / label it?

Tags: javascript, debugging, console

Given a declaration like

`myobj = {a:1, b:2};`

I can write `console.dir(myobj)`.  This results in

```
{ a: 1, b: 2 }
```

But say I want to remind myself, in a complex debugging session, what the `console.dir` is about:

I can write

`console.log("myobj"); console.dir(myobj);`

This will print

```
myobj
{ a: 1, b: 2 }
```

But it's a bit clunky.

Using `console.log("myobj:" + myobj);`

prints out

```
myobj:[object Object]
```

which doesn't work at all.  Is there a better way to *label* a `console.dir`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just wrap your named variable in an object and the name will then be visible as the first layer of expansion.

```js
myobj = {a:1, b:2};

console.dir({myobj});
```

---

You can also use "groups" if you want the top-level wrapper to be your variable's name. Probably you'd want to do this with some sort of helper (and I don't really even suggest it, but it may meet your needs so just showing it as a demonstration):

```js
function labeledConsoleDirGroup(wrappedVar) {
  const varName = Object.keys({myobj})[0];
  console.group(varName);
  console.dir(wrappedVar[varName]);
  console.groupEnd(varName);
}

// Later ...
const myobj = {a: 1, b: 2};
labeledConsoleDirGroup({myobj});
```

Note that this doesn't work in the in-built code snippet runner since it doesn't support groups. But it looks like this in Chrome:

[image: looks like this in Chrome]

Answer (score 0):

dir and log take multiple arguments, you are getting that last output because you can't concatenate a string to an object, here is a proper way:

```js
console.log("myobj:", myobj);
```

Use a comma and just pass multiple arguments instead.

Comment: good call.  re multiple arguments, `console.log` does work as expected in browsers and Node.  `console.dir("myobj", myobj)` however works in browsers but not in Node: `myobj` is not printed out, only the label.

Comment: just tried console.dir("myobj", myobj) in Chrome.  Only prints out the label.

Answer (score 0):

If using Node.js, you can [print the label without a trailing newline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6157497/1079869) by using `process.stdout.write`:

```js
function inspect(label, data) {
  process.stdout.write(`${label}: `)
  console.dir(data, { depth: null })
}
```

`{ depth: null }` is kind of irrelevant here, but it's also the reason why I use `console.dir` in Node.js; it allows [logging objects without deeply nested sub-objects being abbreviated as `[Object]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10729276/1079869) and arrays being abbreviated as `[Array]`.

Example:

```js
const myobj = {
  foo: {
    bar: {
      baz: {
        qux: true,
        ham: 'spam',
      },
      items: [1, 2, 3],
    },
  },
}

console.log('my object:', myobj)
//=> my object: { foo: { bar: { baz: [Object], items: [Array] } } }

inspect('my object', myobj)
//=> my object: {
//     foo: { bar: { baz: { qux: true, ham: 'spam' }, items: [ 1, 2, 3 ] } }
//   }
```